# Is there any way to distinguish between 'parameter has no default value' and 'paratemer's default value is null' in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to make a debug tool: some stuff which gives a package name and generate debug wrapper for it (package with similar procedures; these procedures would log a call, parameter values, execute original procedure and log a call result).

Generally I did it, but I found a bad case: while looking into USER_PROCEDURES and USER_ARGUMENTS there are no any difference between parameters without default values and parameters with null default value. Is there any way to distinguish it?

Now I just place 'default null' to any wrapper's 'in' parameter without one, but it's not nice for me. Second way I found is to parse USER_SOURCE, but this is generally nasty, I guess.

=== Edit: thanks to @phonetic_man, for Oracle 11 there is USER_ARGUMENTS.DEFAULTED column. Is there decision for Oracle 10? ===

Comment: There is a column in the ALL_ARGUMENTS table named DEFAULTED which specifies whether the argument is defaulted or not. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1014.htm

Comment: What exactly is the idea of defaulting a Parameter with NULL??? Should be the same as no Default at all...

Comment: @Tyron78 - it isn't quite the same; if you have it defaulted to null you can leave that argument out of the call, if you don't you have to include the argument explicitly as null.

Comment: Ah, stupid me... you are right - I forgot about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @phonetic_man noted ina comment, in 11g the `user_arguments` view has a `defaulted` column. That isn't present in earlier versions. In 10g there's a `sqljutl` package, [as part of the database's Java installation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b16018/getstart.htm#CHDIFIAJ). That has a `has_default` function you can use:

```
desc sys.sqljutl

...
FUNCTION HAS_DEFAULT RETURNS NUMBER
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 OID                            NUMBER                  IN
 PROC                           CHAR                    IN
 SEQ                            NUMBER                  IN
 OVR                            NUMBER                  IN
...
```

You can pass column values from `user_arguments` into that function:

```
select object_name, package_name, argument_name, data_type, defaulted,
  sys.sqljutl.has_default(object_id,
    case when package_name is null then null else object_name end,
    sequence,
    nvl(overload, 0)) as defaulted
from user_arguments
where package_name = '<YOUR_PACKAGE>'
and object_name = '<YOUR PROCEDURE>';
```

The case expression is there because the function does a slightly different query depending on whether that passed object name is null; it only needs to be set for a package procedure and not for a standalone one. (You can see what it's actually doing in `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/initsqlj.sql`).

```
create package pack42 as
  procedure proc42 (p1 number, p2 varchar2 default null);
end pack42;
/

create package body pack42 as
  procedure proc42 (p1 number, p2 varchar2 default null) is
  begin
    null;
  end proc42;
end pack42;
/

select object_name, package_name, argument_name, data_type, -- defaulted,
  sys.sqljutl.has_default(object_id,
    case when package_name is null then null else object_name end,
    sequence,
    nvl(overload, 0)) as defaulted
from user_arguments
where package_name = 'PACK42'
and object_name = 'PROC42';

OBJECT_NAME PACKAGE_NAME ARGUMENT_NAME DATA_TYPE  DEFAULTED
----------- ------------ ------------- --------- ----------
PROC42      PACK42       P2            VARCHAR2           1
PROC42      PACK42       P1            NUMBER             0
```

and a standalone procedure:

```
create procedure proc42 (p1 number, p2 varchar2 default null) as
begin
  null;
end;
/

select object_name, package_name, argument_name, data_type, -- defaulted,
  sys.sqljutl.has_default(object_id,
    case when package_name is null then null else object_name end,
    sequence,
    nvl(overload, 0)) as defaulted
from user_arguments
where package_name is null
and object_name = 'PROC42';

OBJECT_NAME PACKAGE_NAME ARGUMENT_NAME DATA_TYPE  DEFAULTED
----------- ------------ ------------- --------- ----------
PROC42                   P2            VARCHAR2           1
PROC42                   P1            NUMBER             0
```

The function returns 1 if there is a default, and 0 if there is not.

This works on 11g too, and the `user_arguments.defaulted` column is looking at the same underlying data dictionary information (`argument$.default#`); though there it is converted to Y/N, which you could of course do yourself too.

With the same package build in 11g you can see both flags:

```
select object_name, package_name, argument_name, data_type, defaulted,
  sys.sqljutl.has_default(object_id,
    case when package_name is null then null else object_name end,
    sequence,
    nvl(overload, 0)) as defaulted
from user_arguments
where package_name = 'PACK42'
and object_name = 'PROC42';

OBJECT_NAME PACKAGE_NAME ARGUMENT_NAME DATA_TYPE D  DEFAULTED
----------- ------------ ------------- --------- - ----------
PROC42      PACK42       P1            NUMBER    N          0
PROC42      PACK42       P2            VARCHAR2  Y          1
```